# Error in call to overridden ShowModal while showing modal

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm working with a modal form that is shown as Full Screen. I manage to do that by overriding the virtual `ShowModal()` method.

```
function TfrmComptoir.ShowModal: Integer;
begin
  FullScreen := ReadFromIni('Config.ini', Self.Name, 'FullScreen', False);
  if FullScreen then
  begin
    BorderStyle := bsNone;
    WindowState := wsMaximized;
    width := Screen.Width;
    Height := Screen.Height;
  end else
  begin
    BorderStyle := bsSizeable;
    WindowState := wsMaximized;
  end;

  Result := inherited;
end;
```

This is the procedure where I show the form:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.btnComptoirClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmComptoir := TfrmComptoir.Create(nil);
  try
    frmComptoir.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(frmComptoir);
  end;
end;
```

On my modal form, I have a button to let the user switch between Full Screen and Normal mode. Here is the problem. I cannot call the `ShowModal()` method again, as I get an error:

> cannot make a visible window modal

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You seem to be saying you want to call ShowModal while the screen is already showing modally - or have I misunderstood? Can you provide a [MCVE] so we can see your problem? How does the button you talk about work?

Comment: Use Monitor.Width/Height instead of Screen.Width/Height in case a user launches the form on a non-primary monitor having a different resolution than the primary monitor.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `ShowModal()` while the Form is already showing. Unlike `Show()`, `ShowModal()` can only be called once at a time, the Form must be closed before `ShowModal()` can be called.

What you can do instead is move the property-twiddling code into a method of its own, and then call that method inside of both `ShowModal()` and the button's `OnClick` handler, eg:

```
function TfrmComptoir.ShowModal: Integer;
begin
  SetFullScreen(ReadFromIni('Config.ini', Self.Name, 'FullScreen', False));
  Result := inherited;
  WriteToIni('Config.ini', Self.Name, 'FullScreen', FullScreen);
end;

procedure TfrmComptoir.Button1Click(Sender);
begin
  SetFullScreen(not FullScreen);
end;

procedure TfrmComptoir.SetFullScreen(Value: Boolean);
begin
  FullScreen := Value;
  if FullScreen then
  begin
    BorderStyle := bsNone;
    WindowState := wsMaximized;
    Width := Screen.Width;
    Height := Screen.Height;
  end
  else
  begin
    BorderStyle := bsSizeable;
    WindowState := wsMaximized;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: if i do so FullScreen won't be as it should windows taskbar still on top and ModalForm behind

Comment: i success to achieve the goal with TTimer on the main form

Comment: [How do I switch a window between normal and fullscreen?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353)

Comment: [How do I cover the taskbar with a fullscreen window?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050505-04/?p=35703/)

Comment: it will be very nice if some one provide delphi code to those link i'm very begginner at c/c++ and WinApi